# Error when trying to use ttf font

Tags: fonts, xetex

I installed a ttf font with Font Book, but when I try to compile a document with it using xelatex I get no pdf output and the following errors:

> kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 AGaramondPro-Regular.otf
>   mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for AGaramondPro-Regular.otf.
>   mktexpk: perhaps AGaramondPro-Regular.otf is missing from the map file.
>   kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
>   xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without .vf or "physical" font for PDF output...

Any help would be truly appreciated. I use texlive 2017 on OS X Sierra.

Comment: `xelatex` requires a font to be in system path, *not* in LaTeX font path. Also, you will want to check if the font has read permission e.g. install using superuser permission, but do not provide any read permission to general users. With my zero knowledge of OS X, these are the only comments I can make.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I think it does find the font. It was not installed earlier, and the error I got then was a clear 'cannot find font' error type.

Comment: Is the fontspec package loaded? It should be.

Comment: It is but I will double check

Comment: You are saying that you installed a ttf-font, but the message complains about an otf. Is it really a ttf? And if yes, how are you calling it in your document?